# Speed up unit tests by not building the context message unless the assertion fails

Tags: c#, performance, unit-testing

I have a suite of unit tests that are running quite slowly because they all do something like this:

```cs
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, message: getDetailedErrorContext(expected, Actual));
```

when profiling unit tests, most time is spent generating these detailed error context messages that never end up getting used, because tests are passing.

Does `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` inherently support lazily-generated error messages? I noticed all test methods have an overload e.g.:

```cs
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, message, params object[] parameters);
```

Which lets me pass objects into a format string, but I'm not clear on how I can use that when e.g. the message is generated as something like

```cs
Assert.AreEqual(expected.Count, actual.Count, "All the items in the list are: " +
    String.Join(", ", actual.Select(o => $"[{o.Id}: {o.Description}]"));
```

Is there some existing class I can use that will evaluate to my desired message if (and only if) the test assertion fails? Ideally I'd like to have a solution like:

```cs
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, () => getDetailedErrorContext(expected, Actual));
```

Where the lambda is never evaluated if the assertion doesn't fail.

---

Note, I've considered a solution like replacing all assertion methods with e.g.:

```cs
if (expected != actual)
    Assert.Fail(getDetailedErrorContext(expected, Actual));
```

But I don't like this for a few reasons (such as not wanting to replicate things like `Assert.AreEqual<double>(`'s build-in delta tolerance, and overall difficulty this would create in refactoring our test suite.)

Comment: You could probably do something with interpolated string handlers https://sergeyteplyakov.github.io/Blog/c%2310/2021/11/08/Dissecing-Interpolated-Strings-Improvements-In-CSharp-10.html. `Debug.Assert` uses this language feature, but the other assert methods do not (yet).

Comment: @JeremyLakeman thanks for the read - a very interesting article and cool new feature. Unfortunately, as you suggested, it's moreso on Microsoft to update `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert` methods with overloads to accept an `InterpolatedStringHandler` message argument, and to not invoke `ToStringAndClear()` unless the assertion fails. With any luck, they'll flesh this out in the future. (Personally, I'm stuck on C# 7.3 features until we can migrate our project off of .NET Framework, so I can't roll my own to do the same even if I wanted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, for lack of a more obvious solution, I've created the following wrapper around `Lazy<T>` whose only difference is that it will actually resolve the value when `ToString()` is called:

```cs
public class LazyString : Lazy<string>
{
    public LazyString(Func<string> stringBuilder) : base(stringBuilder) { }
    public override string ToString() => Value;
}
```

I can then use this as:

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "{0}", new LazyString(() =>
    getDetailedErrorContext(expected, Actual)));
```

It's a bit ugly and error prone (if one forgets to insert the format string `"{0}"`, but it works and is the best I could come up. Sadly the  `Assert` class is sealed, so I can't even cleanly extend it with my own overloads.

Comment: I ran into this issue just yesterday, this is a great solution